# undefined: Error: Global config has not been defined yet - Playwright component test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, playwright

I'm attempting to implement Playwrights component test on a grid.  Here's the component test:

```js
import { test, expect } from "@playwright/experimental-ct-react";
import InvoicesTable from "../../../../src/shared/inventory/InvoicesPage/InvoicesTable/InvoicesTable";
import mockComponentInvoices from "../../../../src/shared/inventory/mocks/componentMockInvoices";

test.describe("Invoice Table Renders Component Tests: ", () => {

    test("component renders", async ({ mount }) => {
        const component = await mount(
        <InvoicesTable invoices={ mockComponentInvoices }/>);

        await expect(component).toContainText('email');
    });
});
```

Here's the error:

undefined: Error: Global config has not been defined yet.
at GlobalConfig.get (http://localhost:3100/assets/index.b07305db.js:105442:13)

This is a React app.

I have one Component test running, but the new one I created is displaying that error message on execution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is caused by importing `mockComponentInvoices`

This is a [known limitation](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-components#q-i-cant-import-anything-other-than-the-components-from-tsxjsxcomponent-files) of Playwright component tests:

> you can only import your components from your test file

Unfortunately, I still haven't figured out what they mean about how to resolve this issue.